# SQL MAX() value across 2 or more queries

Tags: sql, max

This seems like a basic action in SQL, but it has me stumped.

I have about 2 different subqueries, each grouped by `LOCATION_ID` that contain a date column. For example, one query includes a listing of `WORKORDER` records while another query pulls records from the `NOTE` table. Both of these queries includes a join to the `LOCATION` table allowing me to group by `LOCATION_ID`.

My goal is to pull the latest date of contact at that particular location and that can be in the form of a workorder, note date, followup date, etc. which are stored in different tables. So ideally I would have a query grouped by `LOCATION_ID` that shows the latest date of contact for that location.

I would post SQL but I don't have anything that is currently working for me. Any ideas on how to approach this type of scenario?

Thanks!

```
SELECT 
   L.LOCATION_ID, Max(MaxDate) 
FROM 
   LOCATION AS L
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       LOCATION_ID, Max(dbo.LeadNote.NoteDate) AS MaxDate 
    FROM 
       LeadNote 
    INNER JOIN 
       LOCATION ON LeadNote.LOCATION_ID = LOCATION.LOCATION_ID 
    GROUP BY 
       LOCATION_ID) T1 ON L.LOCATION_ID = T1.CONTACTLOCATION_LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       LOCATION_ID, Max(dbo.WORKORDER.WORKORDER_DATECREATED) AS MaxDate 
    FROM 
       WORKORDER 
    INNER JOIN 
       LOCATION ON LOCATION_ID = WORKORDER_LOCATION_ID 
    GROUP BY 
       LOCATION_ID) T2 ON L.LOCATION_ID = T2.CONTACTLOCATION_LOCATION_ID`
```

Comment: Please share what you have.

Comment: `UNION` the queries, and use that as a subselect and `MAX` around it ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, why don't you post that as an answer? He's correct, that would probably be the best solution. Reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: @rageit I've attached some code above.

Comment: @RemedialBear Thanks for pointing that out. It is just, I dislike writing one line answers without much explanation so I default to writing comments that answer instead. Maybe its a bad habit :)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I tried that but I still need to maintain my `LOCATION_ID` grouping. Assuming I wouldn't be able to do that without some sort of join? That's where I'm having trouble.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - I agree, but comments are easily overlooked by people having similar problems :)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I think I've got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using UNION to get a single sql result, then wrap it and give it an alias, and then apply a MAX on the field you wish, which both queries return. Keep in mind that to use UNION both queries must return the same set of field names.

Ex:

```
Query A:

   Select a, b, c from T1 where....

Query B:
   Select a, f, e from T2 where...


you would have:

  SELECT MAX(e)
  FROM
    ( 
     (Select a, b, c, NULL as f, NULL as e from T1 where....)
     UNION
     (Select a, NULL as b, NULL as c, f, e from T2 where...)
    ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a join you can use a case statement to fetch the larger date.

```
SELECT
   L.LOCATION_ID,
   (CASE WHEN(T2.MaxDate IS NULL OR T1.MaxDate > T2.MaxDate)
   THEN T1.MaxDate
   ELSE T2.MaxDate
   END) MaxDate
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
   L.LOCATION_ID, Max(MaxDate) 
FROM 
(
   (
    SELECT 
        LOCATION_ID, Max(LeadNote.NoteDate) AS MaxDate 
    FROM 
        LeadNote 
    JOIN 
        LOCATION 
    ON 
        LeadNote.LOCATION_ID = LOCATION.LOCATION_ID 
    GROUP BY 
        LOCATION_ID
   )
UNION 
   (
    SELECT 
       LOCATION_ID, Max(WORKORDER.WORKORDER_DATECREATED) AS MaxDate 
    FROM 
       WORKORDER 
    JOIN 
       LOCATION ON LOCATION_ID = WORKORDER_LOCATION_ID 
    GROUP BY 
       LOCATION_ID
   )
)
```

It may need a little tweaking...but kudos to the comment by @DrCopyPaste if this works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple join and a case statement:

```
SELECT 
   L.LOCATION_ID, 
   CASE WHEN(Max(LeadNote.NoteDate) IS NULL OR Max(LeadNote.NoteDate) > Max(WORKORDER.WORKORDER_DATECREATED) 
     THEN Max(LeadNote.NoteDate) 
     ELSE Max(WORKORDER.WORKORDER_DATECREATED) end AS maxDate
FROM 
   LOCATION AS L
LEFT JOIN LeadNote ON LeadNote.LOCATION_ID = LOCATION.LOCATION_ID 
LEFT JOIN WORKORDER ON L.LOCATION_ID = WORKORDER_LOCATION_ID 
GROUP BY L.LOCATION_ID
```